# how do I get to the snifit or whifit level?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

I have these levels in world 3 unlocked:

- 3-1, Leaflitter Path
- 3-2, The Bafflewood
- 3-3, Wiggler's Tree House
- 3-4, Strike Lake
- 3-5, Loop Loop River
- And 3-6, Outlook Point.

Is there anything like a secret comet piece to get? I don't know how to get to Snifit or Whifit. (I think Snifit or Whifit's W1-10)

Comment: There was a link to a walkthrough in one of your other questions.  Have you given that a shot?

Answer (score 1):

`Snifit or Whifit` takes places in W3-10, `Stump Glade`.

You won't be able to continue through to Stump Glade until you complete the next 3 worlds.  I think that a descriptive walkthrough of each level required to get to this point is beyond the scope of this question, so I will instead point you in the right direction.

**Unlocking W3-7:**

Return to `Wiggler's Tree House`.  Recall that there are 3 stumps in the room where you find Wiggler -- on top of each stump is a Comet Piece, but some are inaccessable because their scraps have been ripped out of the world.  If you've completed through W3-6, then you should have the appropriate scrap to fix one of the stumps.

If you do not have the appropriate scrap to continue on, you may find it in W3-5, `Loop Loop River`.  It is in the middle island in the first area of the level, stuck to a small hedge.

`Paperize` to fix the stump, and obtain the Comet Piece.  On a more general note, the Comet Pieces in Wiggler's Tree House are the key to continuing on to the remainder of World 3.

By obtaining the Comet Pieces in the next 3 worlds and completing the objective in Wiggler's Tree House, you should be able to continue through World 3.

Comment: Thanks, but I already figured it out. :/